# $f(x)$ has a factor $(x-r)$, if and only if $f(r) = 0$ - why can't $f(r)$ be a factor of $(x-r)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

It is clear from the polynomial remainder theorem that $(x-r)$ is a factor of $f(x)$ if $f(r) = 0$

Is there no function $f(r)$ which is a factor of $(x-r)$? does this only happen when $f(r) = 0$?

$f(x) = (x-r)*g(x) + f(r)$

Supposing $f(r)/(x-r) = h(x)$
$\implies
f(x) = (x-r)(g(x)+h(x))$

We can reverse the remainder theorem to $f(r)
\rightarrow
f(r) = -(x-r)*g(x)-f(x)$

This leads nowhere

Edit1: All functions in the question above are polynomials

Comment: I changed it to x, initially though it could represent integers

Comment: $f(r)$ is not a function. It is the value of the polynomial $f(x)$ at $x=r$. In other words, it is a plain number. We can think of it as a constant polynomial. Should it happen that $f(r)\neq0$, then every polynomial $g(x)$ is divisible by $f(r)$ simply because we can divide all the coefficient of $g(x)$ by $f(r)$.

Comment: In other words, you seem to be confused about the meaning of either *function* or *factor* (or possibly both).

Answer (score 0):

By division algorithm, the degree of the remainder $f(r)$ is less than the degree of $x-r$, hence $f(r)=0$ or $\deg f(r)=0$, which means $f(r)$ is some non-zero constant.

> Supposing $f(r)/(x-r) = h(m)$

As you said here, if $f(r)=0$ then $h(m)=0$, it holds.

But if $f(r)=c\neq0$, you get: $c=(x-r)h(m)$, which doesn't hold.